# What are good cross-platform peer to peer video streaming frameworks for mobile?

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, p2p, video-processing

What frameworks/libraries exist that can be used to implement video chat/calling, ala Skype, that run on multiple mobile platforms, at least iOs and Android?

My understanding is that there are two main components to video calling: 
1. Networking, which I suppose peer to peer is what would make most sense for this application 
2. Video processing and streaming

Here some related frameworks I found:

- Doubango - http://www.doubango.org/ (From what I can see this would do the job)
- XMPP - http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/ (Not sure this supports video and is not p2p)
- LIBAV - http://libav.org (This seems to deal with the video processing but not the networking)

Are there other frameworks?
I'd like to also learn about the challenges of doing video calling/chat well.

The video calling I'm needing should includes voice and not rely on phone service.